# C++ Ignore string argument

Tags: c++

I have built a program that create,insert a text into .txt file and now I need to add a small feature where I need to write a function that displays list of files in the directory.

```
int main() {

    display_duration_start();

    std::string VALID_COMMANDS[] = {"CREATE_FILE;","APPEND_TEXT;","DISPLAY_FILE;"};
    
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 1;
    std::string insert;

    while(std::getline(std::cin, insert) && insert != "quit") {
        if (insert == "")
            continue;
        
        std::string command, item,item1,item2;
        std::vector<std::string> items;
        std::stringstream ss(insert);

        if (!std::getline(ss, command, ' ')) {
            std::cout << "Unknown command: `" + command + "`" << '\n';
            break;
        }
        
        while (std::getline(ss, item, ' ')) {
            items.push_back(item);
        }

        if (items.size() == 0) {
            std::cout << "Usage: " + command + " <argument>" << '\n';
            continue;
        }
        
        if(std::find(std::begin(VALID_COMMANDS), std::end(VALID_COMMANDS), command) == std::end(VALID_COMMANDS)) {
            std::cout << "Command not found: " + command << '\n';
            break;
        }

        for(auto& item: items) 
            if(command == "CREATE_FILE;") {
                create_file(item);
            }

            if(command == "APPEND_TEXT";) {
                append_text(item);
            }
            
            if(command == "DISPLAY_FILE;") {
                display_file();
            }
    }
}
```

Now that when I typed in `DISPLAY_FILE;` on my console then it throws this: `Usage: DISPLAY_FILE; <argument>`. Well obviously the output raised because it needed an argument, but how do I make it so that it doesn't need to have a argument?

Function of `display_file()` (not sure if its necessary to be informed):

```
void display_file() {
    struct dirent *d;
    DIR *dr;
    dr = opendir("C:\\schema_location");
    if(dr != NULL)
    {
        printf("");
        for(d=readdir(dr); d!=NULL; d=readdir(dr))
        {
            printf("%s\n", d->d_name);
        }
        closedir(dr);
    }
    else
        printf("\nERROR: Cannot retrieve file from the current directory");
}
```

Comment: Right now, your `if(items.size() == 0)` is testing that you have an argument after the initial command name. If you don't want that, then you should change that statement. Do you always need an argument, or only for certain commands?

Comment: The command to call `display_file()` is `DISPLAY_FILE` not `DISPLAY SCHEMA` as you wrote in the question

Comment: @FCo I need argument for only certain commands which is `CREATE_FILE` and `APPEND_TEXT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a list of commands which don't need arguments and check it together with the presence of arguments. The code below should make the work

```
int main() {

    //display_duration_start();

    std::string VALID_COMMANDS[] = { "CREATE_FILE;","APPEND_TEXT;","DISPLAY_FILE;" };
    std::string NO_ARGUMENT_COMMANDS[] = { "DISPLAY_FILE;" };

    int sum = 0;
    int count = 1;
    std::string insert;

    while (std::getline(std::cin, insert) && insert != "quit") {
        if (insert == "")
            continue;

        std::string command, item, item1, item2;
        std::vector<std::string> items;
        std::stringstream ss(insert);

        if (!std::getline(ss, command, ' ')) {
            std::cout << "Unknown command: `" + command + "`" << '\n';
            break;
        }

        while (std::getline(ss, item, ' ')) {
            items.push_back(item);
        }

        if (items.size() == 0 &&
            std::find(std::begin(NO_ARGUMENT_COMMANDS), std::end(NO_ARGUMENT_COMMANDS), command) == std::end(NO_ARGUMENT_COMMANDS)
            ) {
            std::cout << "Usage: " + command + " <argument>" << '\n';
            continue;
        }

        if (std::find(std::begin(VALID_COMMANDS), std::end(VALID_COMMANDS), command) == std::end(VALID_COMMANDS)) {
            std::cout << "Command not found: " + command << '\n';
            break;
        }

        for (auto& item : items)
        {
            if (command == "CREATE_FILE;") {
                create_file(item);
            }

            if (command == "APPEND_TEXT";) {
                append_text(item);
            }
        }

        if (command == "DISPLAY_FILE;") {
            display_file();
        }
    }
}

void display_file() {
    struct dirent* d;
    DIR* dr;
    dr = opendir("C:\\schema_location");
    if (dr != NULL)
    {
        printf("");
        for (d = readdir(dr); d != NULL; d = readdir(dr))
        {
            printf("%s\n", d->d_name);
        }
        closedir(dr);
    }
    else
        printf("\nERROR: Cannot retrieve file from the current directory");
}
```